# Extracting quoted part with nested quotation

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract this substring `'"double quotes" are allowed inside ''single-quoted'' strings.'` from this string `'"double quotes" are allowed inside ''single-quoted'' strings.' DEFAULT ''`. I understand why my current attempt won't work but I couldn't find any solutions without hardcoding the DEFAULT token.

```
const str = `COMMENT '"double quotes" are allowed inside ''single-quoted'' strings.' DEFAULT ''`;
const reg = /COMMENT\s+(['"]).*?\1/;
console.log(str.match(reg)[0]);
```

If I remove the non-greedy identifier, it matches the whole string which is not what I want.
https://regexr.com/7cktk

Updated:
The opening and closing quotes could be a single quote, a double quote or a backtick. i.e. ['"`]. The string I provided is just an example. Inside the quotes, there could be any characters.

Comment: These kinds of strings are better parsed with some regular string parser, as even https://regex101.com/r/RKyP4h/1 might get tricked.

Comment: The problem is that any character can be included in the string. Your solution seems to be working with the string I provided but if the string is `"'Single quotes are allowed inside "double-quoted" strings." DEFAULT ''` That won't work. 
The opening and closing quote could be either a single quote or a double quote. I'll update my question. Thanks for bring it out

Comment: Why is the expected output not ending in the second single quote, as in `'"double quotes" are allowed inside '`? Is `''` (two single quotes) an escaping mechanism? If so, is there an escaping mechanism for double quotes too? Is the "DEFAULT" changing the behavior of the parser?

Comment: My bad. It actually works. `"'Single quotes are allowed inside ""double-quoted"" strings." DEFAULT ''` I forget to escape the double quotes.

Comment: I can confirm that the regex @WiktorStribiżew provided works with my case. I wonder, would that also work if I also want to handle the backtick?

Comment: After looking further at Wiktor regex, this is the regex to handle the backtick:
(?:'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'|"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|`[^`]*(?:``[^`]*)*`)
I removed the positive lookbehind group as I don't understand why we need that,

Comment: Ok, right, in this case, the lookbehind is not correct, as the char I was checking was the same as the boundary char. So, the lookbehind can be removed. ```'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'|`[^`]*(?:``[^`]*)*`|"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"``` will work since the string would be invalid otherwise.